# Load .txt data from file explorer to Chart in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have list of array that hold the value of X & Y and it save in .txt file. I also have the button "Load data from computer".

Now i want to create function where when the user click the load button, it will open the file explorer directory, user then able to choose the file. When user click the file, the system will automatically load and plot the data in the .txt files to the chart where the graph are created.

I'm having trouble with this function,can someone help me with this function?

Comment: Split your big question into small and you will find everything you need.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136383/reading-a-text-file-using-openfiledialog-in-windows-forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. use `openfiledialog` to open the file explorer
2. use `text reader` to read the text file
3. use any commercial chart control to render the data to chart