# Taking file input from OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I looked around for an answer to this and couldn't find anything. All I need to do is take an input from a text file with multiple lines selected from an OpenFileDialog box. Here's a selection from my code:

```
if (theDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((myStream = theDialog.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    using (myStream)
                    {
                        //I need this to take input given from OpenFileDialog

                        
                        this.read_display.Text = input;
                    }
                }
            }
```

I'm probably just overlooking something really obvious, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What do you mean by ‘take input’? The file name?

Comment: what do you mean by `multiple lines selected from an OpenFileDialog box`?? Multiple files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading a text file using OpenFileDialog in windows forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136383/reading-a-text-file-using-openfiledialog-in-windows-forms)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the text from `stream`, you can create a `StreamReader` instance and call method [`ReadToEnd()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readtoend?view=net-5.0).

```
string input;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myStream))
{
    input = sr.ReadToEnd());
}
```